# LM7805 in LTspice

Tags: voltage-regulator, spice

How can I use the LM7805 regulator in LTspice? I know it's about importing the third party components, but I am not getting it. Can somebody help please?

Comment: Try to use LT1086-5 or LT1117-5 instead.

Comment: I see. Do they work like Lm7805? I mean 5 volt at the output whatever is the input?

Comment: Yes, but all of those IC voltage regulators need to have Vin > Vout.

Comment: There are some suggestions here: https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/lm7805-spice-model.134123/

Comment: That the 78XX series have "volt[s] at the output whatever is the input" is a bit of a misconception.  Mostly, yes, the 78XX series work as a "Vout+3 to Vout" voltage converters, but sometimes they don't (for example, with a floating ground or if you accidentally try to get a 78XX to sink current into its output.)  There is a LM78XX schematic in the .../examples/Educational directory worth understanding. The LT1085 series is a resonable substitute, but it's an LDO whose characteristics are quite different from the 78XX series in some respects.

Answer (score 0):

I obtained the spice model of LM7805 from [here](https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/lm7805-simulation.126081/).The simulation result is given below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simulation with a model I happen to have:

[image]

There are plenty of online tutorials on importing 3rd party models. I suggest getting
Александр Бордодынов's (Alex Bordodynov's)  library, more information [here](https://ltwiki.org/?title=Components_Library_and_Circuits).